# ¿Dónde filtrar y construir datos antes de pasarlos a props?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

(La plataforma actual funciona con react-redux)

Hola tengo un Componente Maestro

```
<Maestro />
```

Cuyo render tiene otros componentes `<Poster />`, `<Detalles />`, `<Botones />`

Para detalles recibo 3 props algo como:

Nombre, año y descripción.

Sin embargo estas 3 propiedades se tienen que armar con una serie de filtrados complejos, consulta de apis y concatenación de distintos puntos que no vale la pena señalar.

```
<Detalles 
  nombre={buildedName}
  ano={readableYear}
  descripcion={validatedDescription}>
```

Debido a tantas funciones stateless y cosas asi, el componente `<Maestro >`esta lleno de métodos que validan, filtran, concatenan, etc.

¿Donde podría colocar esta logica? ya que `<Detalles />` no lleva mas que sus acciones internar.

PD: El *store* actual, esta sobre poblado por malas practicas, por lo que de ser posible  no quiero agregar mas dispatchers, ni actions, ni props al store ya que esta información solo va al final.

Gracias :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PD: El store actual, esta sobre poblado por malas prácticas, por lo que de ser posible no quiero agregar mas dispatchers, ni actions, ni props al store ya que esta información solo va al final.

Esto ya dice mucho del problema en sí ;) Cuando hay problemas de diseño y/o arquitectura, lo máximo que podemos hacer es que *"simplemente funcione"*.

> Debido a tantas funciones stateless y cosas así, el componente está lleno de métodos que validan, filtran, concatenan, etc. ¿Donde podría colocar esta lógica? ya que  no lleva más que sus acciones internas.

La respuesta depende de qué tan necesario sean estas listas en el componente padre.

Cuando trabajamos con componentes, debemos cambiar nuestra forma de pensar y adecuarnos a dicha metodología. Un componente es una unidad de código con una funcionalidad específica; es decir, **un componente debe representar una responsabilidad concreta y atómica**, de preferencia.

Así, cuando identifiquemos dicha responsabilidad, **se abstrae toda la lógica que debe trabajar funcionalmente** en el componente mismo, obviamente no lógica compartida como son los servicios, etc.

---

**Respuesta**

Identifica la funcionalidad de dicho componente y toma en cuenta los siguientes puntos:

- ¿Dicho componente tiene una única responsabilidad? Si la respuesta es no, plantéate desglosar el componente.
- ¿La información que se le es pasada por propiedades es necesaria en el componente que las provee (padre). Si la respuesta es no, mueve dicho código al componente responsable.

Comment: La primera SI, el componente solo hace una cosa y nada mas. Para la segunda la información SI se utiliza, pero de distinta forma (es decir antes de filtrarla)

Comment: @elporfirio Podrías crear un utilitario o helper que se encargue de filtrar; así no sobrecargas el componente padre con lógica innecesaria. De esta manera ganas limpieza y mantenibilidad.